# "The user must be authenticated when the Login finishes successfully."

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

This exception is generated for a small subset of users on my silverlight application. It's a 3 year old app, which previously had no issues logging in. I switched the data access tech from linq2sql model to EF6.

```
AuthenticationService.Login(userName, password, bool..., string...)
```

The above method completes as normal for each user. Database stuff happens fine, just the same for all users, however for a small number of them the UserBase object which is returned has the IsAuthenticated boolean property set false, which causes the exception.

```
   at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.LoginResult..ctor(IPrincipal user, Boolean loginSuccess)
   at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.WebAuthenticationService.EndLogin(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.LoginOperation.EndCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationOperation.End(IAsyncResult result)
```

As you can see from the stack trace it's running the latest OpenRiaServices.

If anyone has some idea what can cause this sort of issue I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the issue in http://openriaservices.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Server/Framework/ApplicationServices/UserBase.cs

```
        [ProfileUsage(IsExcluded = true)]
        [Exclude]
        public bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name); }
        }
```

Some of my users had empty string as their "credential name", so login succeeded but the flag returned false.